# how to calculate the average temperature of each band of a .grd file?

Tags: gdal, python-2.7

I am having a GRD file in which the temperature at different longitude and latitude are given in a 32x35 array for one day(band),i am having 365 such bands and want to calculate the average of all individual bands.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  At the moment the body of your Question contains only code with no explanation of your Question.  I think you have used the title, which is intended to be a summary of the body, to try and do that.  I recommend that you edit your Question body to incorporate the information in the title, and then re-write the title to be a summary of the Question body.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GDAL to convert each band to an array and get the mean of the array with Numpy.

```
import gdal, numpy

ds = gdal.Open("yourRaster.tif")

bandCount = 1
while bandCount <= ds.RasterCount:
    band = ds.GetRasterBand(bandCount)
    bandArray = band.ReadAsArray()
    print numpy.mean(bandArray)
    bandCount += 1
```